# logback-spring.xml won't append file name

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

This is my first time using logging in spring and I was given a logback-spring.xml to use and tweak. This is what my current logback-spring.xml looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <include 
     resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/my_file_name.log}"/>
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy 
         class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
 </configuration>
```

I have also added the following in my application.properties:

```
logging.config=config/logback-spring.xml
```

When I ran the program, the logs directory was automatically created. However the log present was named my_file_name.log instead of my_file_name.log.2017-10-25.gz as I need and as my logback-spring.xml specifies.

Why is this happening? Is it because of an error in the logback-spring.xml or because I need to specify something else in my application.properites or add something in my pom.xml? Or will the log name automatically change as I run this program again on different days?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right with your third suggestion. I think the rolling policy only kicks in when the logs roll; so they start just being called `${LOG_FILE}`, then when they reach a predefined size and/or date, the file gets renamed to that specified by `fileNamePattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On startup Logback will write to the file defined by `appender/file` and when the rolling policy kicks in Logback will copy the current log file to the file suggested by `appender/rollingPolicy/fileNamePattern`.

In your case the rolling policy will kick in when the day rolls (this is what your pattern - `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}` - means). So every day up to day 10 Logback will roll the current log file and on day 10 it will roll the current log file **and** discard the oldest archived file thereby retaining only `maxHistory` archived files.

Plenty more detail [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#onRollingPolicies).

BTW, your logback-spring.xml does seem to have an error in it, I suspect this ...

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/my_file_name.log}"/>
```

... should be:

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/my_file_name.log"/>
```